# How do I ensure that my HttpClient only gets initialized once in C#?

Tags: c#, concurrency, dotnet-httpclient

As per Microsoft's guidelines, I want to ensure that I use the `HttpClient` correctly by having only a single instance of an `HttpClient` pr. API consumed. I'm a little bit weary about my solution working correctly

I've tried adding a lock around a create function that gets called if the static variable is null.

```
    public class BaseClient
    {
        private static volatile HttpClient _httpClient;
        private static readonly object HttpClientLock = new object();

        public BaseClient(string serviceAddress, string apiKeyRequestHeader, string apiKeyValue)
        {
            CreateClient(serviceAddress, apiKeyValue, apiKeyRequestHeader);
        }

        private void CreateClient(string baseAddress, string apiKeyRequestHeaderValue, string apiKeyRequestHeader)
        {
            if (_httpClient == null)
            {
                lock (HttpClientLock)
                {
                    if (_httpClient == null)
                    {
                        _httpClient = new HttpClient
                        {
                            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)
                        };

                        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKeyRequestHeaderValue))
                            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(apiKeyRequestHeader, apiKeyRequestHeaderValue);
                        _httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to be sure that the `HttpClient` only gets instantiated once for every class, so I don't overflow in usage of sockets. Would this code guarantee that happens?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make sure you have only one instance of `HttpClient` is taking advantage of static initialization which is thread-safe by default (guaranteed by the framework), nicely explained in the [post](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton#cctor) about possible singleton implementations in C#.

Following the example, you can simplify code by avoiding locks:

```
public class BaseClient
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static BaseClient()
    {
    }

    public BaseClient(string serviceAddress, string apiKeyRequestHeader, string apiKeyValue)
    {
        InitializeClient(serviceAddress, apiKeyValue, apiKeyRequestHeader);
    }

    private void InitializeClient(string baseAddress, string apiKeyRequestHeaderValue, string apiKeyRequestHeader)
    {
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKeyRequestHeaderValue))
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(apiKeyRequestHeader, apiKeyRequestHeaderValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that, you can always test your approach and check whether it's possible to have more than one instance at a time.

Note:
Having one instance of HttpClient could cause issues when DNS [changes](https://www.nimaara.com/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/). If you are using .Net Core, then you should use `HttpClientFactory` instead since Microsoft sorted the issue there.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that issue up. I've made sure to set the ConnectionLeaseTimeout and DNS cache. But won't the HTTP Client constantly get configured now in the way you've set it up? I get that it looks a lot more elegant.

Comment: @FrankDrebin893 it will be, you are definitely right, but adding a lock around initialization might cause performance degradation. And since these are only few basic configuration steps, I didn't want to lock them. Definitely, something you can decide to put anyhow.

Comment: That's true, but I figured the lock would never be a performance issue, as the lock is skipped after the first initialization of the HttpClient due to the null check. Would it be a problem in that case?

Comment: @FrankDrebin893 it wouldn't be problem, you can easily lock initialization part. I wouldn't double guard it though - because you will not encounter issues if you configure client more than once.